# Maven - How to configure maven to satisfy these requirements

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I do have trouble setting up maven in a way that would satisfy my requirements. My IDE is eclipse

i am using maven-jar-plugins & maven-sources-plugin to produce some jars

I have a project 'A' that produces 2 .jar files 
 
 - a.jar (includes all binary files) 
 - a-sources.jar (includes all java files)

There is also another project which also produces 2 .jar files
 - b.jar 
 - b-sources.jar

On the 3rd project i am using these .jar (binaries only) so the project compiles and runs etc.

All 3 projects 'A' + 'B' + 'C' are on my workspace

Now: assuming that on the 3rd project i have found some problem with a class that comes from 2nd 'B' project - Normally i could just hold CRTL+click on the ClassName / Method OR click F3 and it would take me to the class or method declaration. With maven i have found that this is not the case, it asks for attaching source.

So i went out and did some googling and i have found a way of downloading these sources and including them in a project in this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>  
......
```

Which SORT of works but its not exactly what i want. When i download these sources and i open declaration for given class/method it opens foo.class. ALTHOUGH!! the b-sources.jar file contains .java files AND NOT .class files.

Anyway how can i set up maven so when i click open declaration of class/method from my 'C' project it will take me to the .java source file of 'B' project so i can modify it instead of .class file which is read only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the maven eclipse plugin, and use the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects"

[image]

Comment: which plugin exactly? i do have Maven eclipse plugin but my UI is different. Is there a way to accomplish this with .pom file ??

Comment: I have the maven eclipse plugin that is in the eclipse market place.  You can't do this from the POM, it's eclipse that needs to know what to do.  Right click on your project, click Properties, then choose the Maven tab.

Comment: Well there is quite a few plugins available on marketplace so if you could be more specific which one i would appreciate it. Also there must be a way of telling eclipse about these dependencies just in the same way as you can tell eclipse (using maven) of linked resources

Comment: I use m2e - "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer) 1.4"

Comment: strange i have the same + extension for WTP and i do not have such option "resolve dependencies from workspace projects"

Comment: Strange, that option has been there for years.  I do remember a couple of years ago that the m2e and WTP were mutually incompatible with each other.  But that was in eclipse 3.7. I would have excepted it to have been addressed in Eclipse 4.2.